# Any reason for JNDI in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, jndi

### Background

We are converting a traditional java application from a war deployed to a tomcat container into a Spring Boot application that runs in an embedded tomcat server. We are currently using JNDI for the database connections which are defined in the `context.xml` in the `conf/` folder in the tomcat instance.

### Problem

There's not a way to do this with a Spring Boot application, not exactly that is. I have found solutions to define the data source with JNDI in a Spring Boot application but it requires all the connection information in the code. This got me thinking, **if the connection info is in the code, is there even a point to be using JNDI?** I thought the point of JNDI was to separate the details of how to connect so that it could be defined per environment.

### Alternative

Define a data source without JNDI and have the connection details be defined externally (e.g., command line params, Spring Cloud Config Server, or something else).

Comment: Spring Boot supports non jndi datasources out of the box, just add some properties to the `application.properties` and be done with it. When using an embedded container there is really no use for JNDI (IMHO). Only when you deploy to a container it might make sense to reuse an existing datasource for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that JNDI was originally conceived as a way to abstract away the specific connection details of a datasource (well, not just datasources, but you get the gist). This abstractin makes sense in general, so JNDI was an officially sanctioned standard that had to be implemented in everything that wanted to be JEE (J2EE? can't remember) compatible.

You still need a configuration abstraction, as you don't want to hardcode all the values for all your different environments in code, but Spring has ready-made solutions for that. Personally I wouldn't bother with JNDI in anything that would never be in an JEE server.

Comment: Right, I'm not saying the connection details shouldn't be abstracted, it was just when I first realized a suggestion to use JNDI in Spring Boot was to code them in and that's what led me to wonder why we should use JNDI at all. Thanks!